# Adding HTML to page based on conditional logic in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` in which I have to fill some data in. I have to render the HTML based on conditions and I am adding data to that `div` using jQuery. Can someone please tell me how I can add the condition based insertion of HTML on the page?

```
      function AddData()
    {   
        var data = "<div><h1>My data</h1>"
             if(jsVariable){
                  <p>The JSVariable is present on page </p>                
                        }
               +"</div>"
            $('.myDiv').after("<br/>"+data);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you simply want to add some extra html content depending on the variable, you are almost done. You just need to add the <p> part to the data (data += "<p>...</p>").

Comment: I have a lot of HTML to add based on certain conditions like if the data is present or not .I used if(jsvariable) example to simplify my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  function AddData(){   
    if(typeOf(jsVariable)!=="undefined"){ 
      var data =  "<div><h1>My data</h1>";
          data += "  <p>The JSVariable is present on page </p>";                
          data += "</div>";
       $('.myDiv').after("<br/>"+data);     
      }
}
```

this should do the trick, but some element with a class of `myDiv` will need to already exist for this to work

```
 <div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks all..Really appreciate so quick responses.

Answer (score 2):

```
  function AddData()
    {   
        var data = "<div><h1>My data</h1>"
             if(jsVariable){
                  data = data + "<p>The JSVariable is present on page </p>"     
              }
             data = data + "</div>"
            $('.myDiv').append("<br/>"+data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'r code is not valid.

Could you explain what do you want to do with

```
if(jsVariable){
    <p>The JSVariable is present on page </p>                
}
+"</div>"
```

If you want to add a html code at ending of a div, you should use

```
$('.myDiv').append('<p>Text text text text</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do?

If you simply want to add some extra html content depending on the variable, you are almost done. You just need to add the `<p>` part to the data `(data += "<p>...</p>")`.

If you're trying to add all of the html based on the variable, put the if statement around the `$(".myDiv").after` (which should be `$(".myDiv").append` btw).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (condition) {
   $('div#yourDivID').html('<p>The JSVariable is present on page </p>');
}
```

In addition to `.html`(which places the html inside your div), you can use other things like append, prepend etc. Check out jQuery's documentation on [DOM Insertion](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/).

Answer (score 0):

simple usage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("p").click(function() {
            var a = $("#div1").text();
            if (a == "one") {
                $("#div2").text(a);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">one</div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <p>click me</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addData(to)
{
    var h1   = $('<h1>').text('My Data');
    var data = $('<div>').append(h1);

    if (window.jsVariable) {
        $('<p>').text('JS Variable is present on the page').appendTo(data);
    }

    to.append(data);
}

addData( $('.myDiv') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/va4n8/

```
function addData() {
    var newDiv = $('<div>');
    newDiv.append($('<h1>').html('My data'));

    if ('jsVariable' in window) {
        newDiv.append($('<p>').html('The JSVariable is present on page'));
    }

    $('.mydiv').after($('<br>')).after(newDiv);
}
```